# How do we use sceneform along with ARCloud anchors?

Tags: arcore

Every time I try to host an anchor "**session.hostCloudAnchor(anchor);**" it shows up **NotTrackingException**.

How can we host and resolve the Anchor that we get from **arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener** ?

This is the  snippet of the code I was using,

```
   arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
    (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {
      Camera camera = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame().getCamera();
      TrackingState cameraTrackingState = camera.getTrackingState();

      if (andyRenderable == null) {
        return;
      }

      if (plane.getType() != Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING) {
        return;
      }

      if (cameraTrackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING && session!= null) {
        // Create the Anchor.
        anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
        try{
        session.hostCloudAnchor(anchor);
        }
        catch (NotTrackingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        setNewAnchor(anchor);
        appAnchorState = AppAnchorState.HOSTING;
        Toast.makeText(HelloSceneformActivity.this, "Now, hosting anchor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

        // Create the transformable andy and add it to the anchor.
        TransformableNode andy = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        andy.setParent(anchorNode);
        andy.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
        andy.select();

        checkUpdatedAnchor();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the **anchor** tracking state & proceed with hosting.

```
override fun onTapPlane(hitResult: HitResult, plane: Plane, motionEvent: MotionEvent?) {


        if (plane.type == Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING) {

            val anchor = hitResult.createAnchor()
            val anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
            anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.arSceneView.scene)

            if (anchor.trackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING) {

                viewModel.hostAnchorToCloud(anchor)

            } 
        }
    }
```

Before hosting an anchor:

- Try to look at the anchor from different angles.
- Move around the anchor for at least a few seconds.
- Make sure you are not too far away from the anchor.

Refer : https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/cloud-anchors-developer-guide-android